# ¿Qué significa exactamente el mensaje sobre la actualización del nivel de API de destino en Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play-console

Más o menos en agosto recibí una advertencia que dice lo siguiente:

> **Actualiza tu nivel de API de destino no más tarde del 1 de noviembre de 2023 para publicar actualizaciones de tu aplicación**
>
> Hemos detectado que tu aplicación está orientada a una versión antigua
> de Android. Para ofrecer a los usuarios una experiencia segura, Google
> Play requiere que todas las aplicaciones cumplan los requisitos de
> nivel de API de destino.
>
> A partir del 1 de noviembre de 2023, si tu nivel de API de destino
> tiene una antigüedad superior a un año respecto al lanzamiento de la
> versión más reciente de Android, no podrás actualizar tu aplicación.
>
> Para seguir actualizando tu aplicación, asegúrate de que esté
> orientada a Android 13 (nivel 33 de la API).

Cabe decir que la fecha que dice ahí es una prórroga. La fecha límite para hacer dicha actualización era el 31 de agosto. Desde julio yo estoy trabajando en una actualización de la aplicación que no está terminada y supuestamente ese plazo termina mañana.

Cuando me puse a revisar más a fondo, parece que el mensaje no se refería al bundle que tengo actualmente en producción, sino a dos pruebas, una abierta y otra cerrada, que estaban basadas en un nivel de API muy antiguo. Como pueden ver en la captura, el bundle en producción está orientado a nivel de API 33.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Viendo que lo que estaba antiguo eran las dos pruebas antes mencionadas, lo que hice fue solicitar que esas pruebas sean pausadas, como pueden ver en el recuadro inferior. Pero en la parte superior sigue apareciendo el mensaje:

> Tomaremos medidas en breve, ya que tu aplicación no cumple las
> políticas del Programa para Desarrolladores de Google Play. Soluciona
> las infracciones lo antes posible.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y ese mismo mensaje aparece también en la parte de **Producción**. De modo que no entiendo nada.

¿Sabe alguno de ustedes si **ese mensaje se refiere a mi aplicación en general**, o **solamente a esas pruebas que estaban en un nivel de API antiguo** y que he solicitado pausar?

Mi problema es que el actual código de la aplicación está como el motor de un vehículo, desmontado por piezas, y no podré armarlo de aquí a mañana.

Comment: si está haciendo referencia a tus dos aplicaciones de prueba, Si tu proyecto de producción esta con una de las ultimas APIS no tendras problemas. Lo que si te sugiero es que esos beta de prueba que tienes actualizalos en lo que tengas tiempo para que no tengas esas alertas. Saludos.

Comment: Hola, tuve este mismo problema, de hecho por la cantidad de apps, tuve que pedir una extensión hasta el 31 de octubre, agregué una respuesta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al recibir un mensaje que indica no cumples con alguna política, puedes revisar en el enlace que indico específicamente cuál es el .APK o .AAB que no cumple con la política:

[image: Google Play problema con política]

Aquí se indica si la app se encuentra en el track de Alpha, Beta Testing o producción.

> ¿Sabe alguno de ustedes si ese mensaje se refiere a mi aplicación en
> general, o solamente a esas pruebas que estaban en un nivel de API
> antiguo y que he solicitado pausar?

**Se refiere a tu aplicación y a tus pruebas que pudieran estar definidas con un API antiguo.**

**Para cumplir con esta política, también hay que cambiar las apps que subiste la prueba abierta y cerrada que no cumplen con estar compiladas con API 33, ya que aunque cambies la de producción continuarás teniendo el mensaje y no te permitirá actualizaciones de la app.**

Tu aplicación en producción puede cumplir con la política; sin embargo, el mensaje se continuará mostrando si no se cumple lo siguiente:

- En Internal Testing, Open Testing, Closed Testing se encuentra un .APK o .AAB que no cumple con la política. En este caso te sugiero subir una actualización en el track que indica se tiene se encuentra un .APK o .AAB que no cumple con la política.
- Si el problema se indica en .APK o .AAB de producción, este debe ser liberado al 100% de los usuarios para que se elimine el mensaje de alerta.

Comment: El problema en mi caso es que el mensaje era confuso, o yo no lo entendí (me refiero a la advertencia de agosto pasado). Pensé que se refería a mi bundle en producción, pero ayer, revisando con más detenimiento, entré en la opción `View affected bundles` y fue ahí cuando vi que se refería a **dos bundles en los canales de prueba que estaban orientados a la API 28**. Ahora mismo estoy intentando subir un `.aab` actualizado a esos canales. Espero me deje, porque llevo dos intentos y los está rechanzando, no sé si es porque los he puesto en pausa ¿?

Comment: Pienso lo mismo que tú, el mensaje en realidad era un poco confuso, de hecho fuí cuestionado porque continuábamos recibiendo mensajes de Google si se había actualizado la app en el track de producción. Al final tuvimos que actualizar los .aab y .apk de pruebas, que en ocasiones eran ya muy antiguos. Si, no lo pongas en pausa, subelo y liberalo al 100% de usuarios en pruebas.

Comment: Sí sí, vaya desastre de mensaje. Los he sacado de pausa y me ha dejado subir el `.abb` y el mensaje se ha quitado.

Comment: @A.Cedano que bien! :D

Comment: Bueno, en la prueba cerrada he podido, pero en la prueba abierta, aún sacándola de pausa, no me deja subir el `.abb`.

Comment: @A.Cedano Si te refieres a la misma app puedes promover la que subiste a prueba cerrada ahora a prueba abierta, no necesitas subir el mismo. AAB a prueba abierta, por cierto tal vez no te lo permite ya que tiene el .AAB el mismo versionCode de la prueba cerrada.,

Comment: Así es, el problema era que intentaba subir el mismo `.abb` dos veces, y eso no lo permite. Lo que he hecho es agregar el último `.abb` también a la prueba abierta **desde la biblioteca**. La cuestión de las pruebas en Play Console es totalmente confusa para mi, ahora parece que me voy enterando, a tropezones.

Comment: Ahora tengo en mi bandeja de entrada el mensaje: *Se ha solucionado una infracción reciente de las políticas relacionada con tu aplicación*. Así que, problema resuelto. El mensaje se refería a las pruebas, no al código en producción.